# Using array as target in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsplumb

I am trying to create connections in jsPlumb from one source to multiple targets. I want to define the targets using an array. However, whenever I try to do this jsPlumb always simply chooses the first item in the array, rather than using all of them.

For example, I define my array like so using the id's of two elements:

```
var test = ['s4', 's3'];
```

Then, the jsPlumb to create the programmatic connection:

```
    jsPlumb.ready(function() {


    jsPlumb.connect({

        source:"element1", 
        target: test,
        anchors:["Left", "Left" ],
        endpoint:"Blank", /* note that you can also make this "image" if you want something fancy */
        endpointStyle:{ fillStyle: "red"},
        paintStyle:{strokeStyle:"red", lineWidth:3},
        connector:[ "Flowchart", { cornerRadius:"200", stub:"40"} ] 

    });


})
```

This only ever creates a connection between #element1 and #s4. What am I getting wrong? I can't find much documentation on how to use an array in the context of a programmatic connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to loop your code for multiple targets like below:

```
var start = 'element1';
var end = ['s4','s3'];    

for(var i=0;i<end.length;i++)
{
        jsPlumb.connect({
                source:start,
                target:end[i],
                connector:[ "Flowchart", { cornerRadius:"200", stub:"40"} ],
                paintStyle:{strokeStyle:"red", lineWidth:3},
                endpointStyle:{ fillStyle: "red"},
                anchors:["Left", "Left" ],
                endpoint:"Blank"
        })
}
```

Similar question: [How can I connect multiple targets from a single source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582995/how-to-connect-multiple-targets-from-a-single-source-in-jsplumb/20781085#20781085)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs, you can't pass an array in the target field of `.connect` method.

DOCS - http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/jsPlumbInstance.html#method_connect

For connecting the same source to multiple targets, just use the `.connect` method multiple times with different target everytime.

If you want to limit the number of connections which can be made from a single endpoint (unlimited by default), then you can use the `maxConnections` property - http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/jsPlumbInstance.html#method_makeTarget